# How to add 'await' at node using jscodeshift?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jscodeshift

I recently have spotted jscodeshift and leveraging it for refactoring.

But I can't find a way to add `await` before the node that I am seeking.

```
// AS-IS
   userEvent.click(a);
   await userEvent.click(b);

// TO-BE
   await userEvent.click(a);
   await userEvent.click(b);
```

This is how I query `userEvent.click`

```
const getFunctionCall = (obj:string, prop:string) => {
     return source.find(j.CallExpression, {
         callee: {
           type: 'MemberExpression',
           object: {
             name: obj
           }, 
           property: {
             name:prop
           }
         }
     })
 }

const clicks = getFunctionCall('userEvent', 'click');
  
  clicks.forEach(i=> {
    if (i.parentPath.value.type !== 'AwaitExpression') {

      // code goes here

    }
  })
```

How can I add `await` before `userEvent` and let the rest code stay same in this case?

I checked out the [document](https://github.com/benjamn/ast-types/blob/master/def/es6.ts) to find out how to build a statement or expression, but it wasn't understandable for me as I've just started to use this. I would appreciate if you can introduce any good materials for this library.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple, you need to wrap the existing CallExpression inside an await expression like this:

```js
// Press ctrl+space for code completion
export default function transformer(file, api) {
  const j = api.jscodeshift;
  const root = j(file.source);
  const body = root.get().value.program.body;

  root.find(j.CallExpression, {
    callee: {
object: {
        name: "userEvent"
      },

      property: {
        name: "click"
      }
    }
  }).filter(path => {
    return path.value.arguments[0].name === "a" ;
  }).replaceWith(path => {
    return j.awaitExpression(path.value)
  });

  return root.toSource();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it was hard to find how to use jscodeshift, or APIs that the library offer. Where did you find it? The example in my question is a simplified version. In real, I don't know what parameter name is given to the method.

Comment: Yes it is hard, You can check the AST in https://astexplorer.net/ and if you are familiar , you can figure out the jscodeshift api. Also check out a declarative codemod engine called JARVIS I built here https://rajasegar.github.io/jarvis/
You can find how to build and find AST nodes using jscodeshift here

Comment: @JunKim if you use TypeScript or set up JSDoc for type info (for JavaScript) it is easier to find all the function signatures. I can provide more info if needed